# Assign different public IPs to different Docker container

Tags: networking, docker, ip, port, docker-compose

I need to run two containers each containing a script binding on a specific (public) IP (11.11.11.20 and 11.11.11.21) The docker host itself is on 10.10.10.222.

I wrote this docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
  nginx-0:
    image: nginx:1.10
    networks:
      app_net:
        ipv4_address: 11.11.11.20

  nginx-1:
    image: nginx:1.10
    networks:
      app_net:
        ipv4_address: 11.11.11.21

networks:
  app_net:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
      - subnet: 11.11.11.20/30
```

My obfuscated `ip a`:

```
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.10.10.222/27 brd 10.10.10.223 scope global eth1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 11.11.11.20/32 brd 11.11.11.20 scope global eth1:0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 11.11.11.21/32 brd 11.11.11.21 scope global eth1:1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

but it tells me **Address already in use**

Is there any solution to do this?

Thanks in advance!
Dominik

Comment: I am not sure, whether this is the reason of your problem, but nevertheless you could try not to use 11.11.11.22 instead of 11.11.11.20. The reason: 11.11.11.20 is the network address and you should not assign this address to any interface. The only usable addresses on 11.11.11.20/30 are 11.11.11.21 and 11.11.11.22 and 11.11.11.21. 11.11.11.20 is the network ID (binary representation is ending with '00') and 11.11.11.23 is the broadcast address (binary representation is ending with '11').

Comment: Thanks for the response! I tried it and with the IPs .21 and .22 on the containers docker responds with Cannot start nginx-0: No available addresses on this pool

Comment: I got them to start with:
subnet: 11.11.11.0/24

but they now have the wrong gateway: 11.11.11.1
and i need a fixed gateway in the subnet of the hosts ip like: 10.10.10.111

any idea how to add that?

Comment: i updated my question because of the new subnet

Comment: I think, it is not a good idea to rewrite your question, since my comment and my answer are referring to your original question. Unfortunately, my answer and your edit were overlapping in time. Can you please reverse your edit and accept the answer instead, if it answers your original question? Thanks. Your question about the gateway is also worth a separate question, since it is a different problem.

Comment: sure thing! thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the addresses to valid values within the 11.11.11.20/30 subnet: nginx-0 and nginx-1 should have the addresses 11.11.11.21 and 11.11.11.22. The address 11.11.11.20 is not valid, since it is the subnetwork address.

You also seem to use addresses on a bridged interface that are outside of the main interface's network 10.10.10.222/27. Nodes in a secondary network can reach the other IP addresses only, if there is a router with interfaces (IP addresses) in both, the primary network and the secondary network. However, this will be hard to achieve in the 11.11.11.20 network, since all available addresses in this network are occupied by your nginx servers. In the case of a bridged network, the easiest solution is to use addresses from the primary network for your nginx servers, and to specify the correct gateway address within the primary network 10.10.10.222/27. Instead, you could use a larger network like 11.11.11.20/27 and place the IP addresses of both nginx servers and a router into it.